# Ajax call result not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this function where on onkeyup it verifies the mobile number whether it exists in the database already or not now the issue is even if the response is "true" it will always show as false

PHP

```
elseif ($action == 'check_mobile_phone')
{

    $mobile = trim($_GET['mobile']);
    $mobile = json_str_iconv($mobile);

    if (mobile_register($mobile))
    {
        echo 'false';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'true';
    }
}
```

Ajax Call

```
function checkMobilePhone(mobile)
{

  if (mobile == '')
  {
   error.find('#mobile_notice_text').html('Mobile number cant be empty.');
   submit_disabled = true;
  }
  else if (!Utils.isMobile(mobile))
  {
    error.find('#mobile_notice_text').html('Please enter mobile number in local format.');
  }

  if( submit_disabled )
  {
    document.forms['formUser'].elements['Submit'].disabled = 'disabled';
    return false;
  }
  Ajax.call( 'user.php?act=check_mobile_phone', 'mobile=' + mobile, check_mobile_callback , 'GET', 'TEXT', true, true );
}
```

Response

```
function check_mobile_callback(result)
{
  var logform = $('form[name="formUser"]');
  var error = logform.find('#mobile_notice');

  if ( result === "true" )
  {
    document.forms['formUser'].elements['Submit'].disabled = '';
  }
  else
  {
    error.find('#mobile_notice_text').html('Phone number already exists.');
    document.forms['formUser'].elements['Submit'].disabled = 'disabled';
  }
}
```

Comment: `if ( result === "true" )` -> may be the result is a `boolean`, try `if (result)` or `if ( result == "true" )`

Comment: If you're really returning a plaintext response from the AJAX call (which isn't a great idea) then check there's no whitespace in the value you return. Try adding `result.trim()` to the `if` statement. Otherwise I'd suggest returning JSON, or some other form of serialised data structure.

Comment: This code is so hard to read, first of all try to refactor to code, make more easy. Maybe you will solve your code making this.

Comment: The only two important lines in the code are `Ajax.call( 'user.php?act=check_mobile_phone', 'mobile=' + mobile, check_mobile_callback , 'GET', 'TEXT', true, true );` and `if ( result === "true" )`. What does this `Ajax.call()` return? edit: I mean what does it pass to the callback?

Comment: add a debugger in callback and see whats in the result. From there you can figure out easily whats wrong with your code.

Comment: Please check the post i have updated the code and added the PHP code aswell

Comment: Have you tried adding `debugger` in the `check_mobile_callback()` and seeing what the passed variable `result` is?

Comment: It seems like there is space in the response i have change the code and added a space before the true and it started working if ( result === " true" )

Comment: @SPK ok but instead you should fix the faulty response instead of making a nasty workaround in your if statement. If you have bad data, sort it out instead of making the system dependent on it. As already mentioned it would be far better to return JSON from the server with a truly boolean true/false value in it instead of a string, then you can't have this kind of issue with spaces or hidden characters.

Comment: please post code for this method mobile_register($mobile)

Answer (score 0):

```
function mobile_register($mobile)
{
    $res = $GLOBALS['db']->getOne("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $GLOBALS['db']->table('users') .
                                  " WHERE mobile_phone = '$mobile'");
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.